# Multiple functions inside variable

Tags: javascript

I want to build a collection of functions that can be accessed from inside and outside. I created a variable like this:

```
var Func = {
    init:function() {...}
}
```

And this works great. But when I add another function to it (`init2`, for example) it doesn't work at all. What can I do?

Comment: Separate them by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seperate them using the `comma ,`

Like this:-

```
var Func = {
    init: function() {}, 
    init1: function() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals). You need to separate properties with a comma.

```
var Func = {
    init: function() {}, // comma
    init2: function() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, use comma to separate functions

```
var Func =
{
    init : function() {...}, // <-----
    init2 : function() {...}
}
```